# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (MVS 2022) (ILNumerics problem in C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, graph, ilnumerics

How to use ILNumerics extension in MVS 2022. I already installed but it could not be use in MVS 2022 in C++. Help.

I already installed and the ILNumerics extension cannot be used. How to use the ILNumerics in MVS2022 in C++.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.